# Is there a second-generation Airport Express 802.11n?

Tags: airport

In late 2011 there were refreshes to Airport Extreme and Time Capsule. At the time there was [speculation](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/09/12/apple_readying_second_generation_of_airport_express_802_11n.html) that there would be a second generation of the Airport Express 802.11n model.

I'm in the market for a new one but I can't find any solid evidence that there was actually a new model ever released. I notice when checking my current model's serial number that Apple specifies it as **AirPort Express 802.11n (1st Gen)**, which makes me think there's a later generation, but again I have no actual info on it.

Does anyone have an answer on this?

Comment: In one sense this question is dated (and out of date) - but it does document the confusion around the product in this time frame. I see no reason to delete it at present, but if you really wish it to be deleted - flag again or @ me in a comment here and I can do that.

Comment: No, that's fine. It likely has enough context that it wouldn't be confusing for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet on a 2nd gen 802.11n Express.

Apple has published [four different manuals](http://support.apple.com/manuals/#airport) on the Airport Express:

- [AirPort Express 802.11n (1st Generation) - Setup Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/AirPort_Express_Setup_Guide.pdf)

The three expresses prior to that were not 802.11n so perhaps that's where the three previous generations (and the 1st and only newer generation names have come to be) A tad confusing, no?

Answer (score 1):

It's out now i guess -- [AirPort Express 802.11n (2nd Generation): Guide to ports and connectors](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5211)